# What would be the easiest way to host an intranet Mono web application?

Tags: web-server, web-applications, intranet, mono

I've just finished migrating a lightweight Microsoft® .NET™ web application to Mono and now I'm looking for a straight-forward way to host such development on a (perhaps virtualized) Ubuntu 10.10 server within an intranet environment. I was wondering if you guys have any advice to share as I'm not quite experienced when it comes to server-side/operations stuff.

I've been checking the related questions but none of them really address the problem particularly regarding the intranet scenario as well as not much quick-start steps/details were provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you need is a `mod_mono` installation on apache, to run ASP.NET applications, the Mono Project wiki has [a guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) on it that includes simple installation instructions on Ubuntu.

About the type of server you are going to use, a real or a virtual server will probably do fine.

Comment: thanks for the contribution, I've found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono particularly informative.